# Request not givining responce in python command

Tags: python, request

`headers={'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.102 Safari/537.36',
... 'accept-language':'en-US,en;q=0.9,bn;q=0.8','accept-encoding':'gzip, deflate, br'}

url='https://www.nseindia.com/api/equity-stock?index=fu_niftybank'
r = requests.get(url,headers=headers).json()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 900, in json
return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\simplejson_init_.py", line 525, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\simplejson\decoder.py", line 370, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\simplejson\decoder.py", line 400, in raw_decode
return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\simplejson\scanner.py", line 79, in scan_once
return _scan_once(string, idx)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\simplejson\scanner.py", line 70, in _scan_once
raise JSONDecodeError(errmsg, string, idx)
simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This error `simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError` means that requests was unable to decode json for the site. I took a look at the link and it's not json it just returns html - https://www.nseindia.com/api/equity-stock?index=fu_niftybank. Must be an issue with the api, not your code.